# Deserialize Avro messages into specific datum using KafkaAvroDecoder

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I'm reading from a Kafka topic, which contains Avro messages serialized using the `KafkaAvroEncoder` (which automatically registers the schemas with the topics). I'm using the maven-avro-plugin to generate plain Java classes, which I'd like to use upon reading.

The `KafkaAvroDecoder` only supports deserializing into `GenericData.Record` types, which (in my opinion) misses the whole point of having a statically typed language. My deserialization code currently looks like this:

```
    SpecificDatumReader<event> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(
        event.getClassSchema() // event is my class generated from the schema
    );
    byte[] in = ...; // my input bytes;
    ByteBuffer stuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(in);
    // the KafkaAvroEncoder puts a magic byte and the ID of the schema (as stored 
    //   in the schema-registry) before the serialized message
    if (stuff.get() != 0x0) {
        return;
    }
    int id = stuff.getInt();

    // lets just ignore those special bytes
    int length = stuff.limit() - 4 - 1;
    int start = stuff.position() + stuff.arrayOffset();

    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(
        stuff.array(), start, length, null
    );
    try {
        event ev = reader.read(null, decoder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I found my solution cumbersome, so I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution to do this.

Comment: Have you come across https://github.com/confluentinc/examples, specifically examples such as https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/SpecificAvroIntegrationTest.java?

Comment: @miguno oh, no, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comment I was able to find the answer. The secret was to instantiate `KafkaAvroDecoder` with a `Properties` specifying the use of the specific Avro reader, that is:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "...");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_C‌ONFIG, "...");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    VerifiableProp vProps = new VerifiableProperties(props);

    KafkaAvroDecoder decoder = new KafkaAvroDecoder(vProps);
    MyLittleData data = (MyLittleData) decoder.fromBytes(input);
```

The same configuration applies for the case of using directly the `KafkaConsumer<K, V>` class (I'm consuming from Kafka in Storm using the `KafkaSpout` from the storm-kafka project, which uses the `SimpleConsumer`, so I have to manually deserialize the messages. For the courageous there is the storm-kafka-client project, which does this automatically by using the new style consumer).

Comment: I think you have a typo. `props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "...");` should be `props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "...");`

Comment: @zzztimbo interesting, I have a project, where `KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CO‌​NFIG` works, but not in other projects :o

Comment: I updated my answer, your way is seems to be more reliable

Comment: What value do I have to put for `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_C‌ONFIG`? Like something random?

Comment: @1290 the URL of your schema registry server

Comment: @kosii Hmm so if I created the Avro schema using spring avro plugin what would I put for this value then?